# Specified time is not supported in this calendar

Tags: datetime, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, arabic

Specified time is not supported in this calendar. It should be between 04/30/1900 00:00:00 (Gregorian date) and 11/16/2077 23:59:59 (Gregorian date), inclusive.
Parameter name: time

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified time is not supported in this calendar. It should be between 04/30/1900 00:00:00 (Gregorian date) and 11/16/2077 23:59:59 (Gregorian date), inclusive.
Parameter name: time

i got this error when trying to use [DataType(DataType.Date)] in MVC 5 with arabic culture

Comment: Unless you edit your question to show the code you are using and the parameters you are passing, it is unlikely that anyone will be able to help you.

Comment: What datepicker are you using? Is the date you are passing to the view within the valid range?

Comment: [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime AvailableFrom
        {get; set;} i'm not using datepicker

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but with Calendar tool in asp.net mvc. I changed calendar to Gregorian and it resolved my issue.

```
var culture = new CultureInfo(cultureCode, true);
//set Gregorian as default calendar
CalendarUtilities.ChangeCalendar(culture, new GregorianCalendar());

public class CalendarUtilities
    {
        private readonly Calendar newCal;
        private readonly bool isGregorian;

        public static void ChangeCalendar(CultureInfo ci, Calendar cal)
        {
            var util = new CalendarUtilities(cal);

            // Is the new calendar already the current calendar?
            if (util.CalendarExists(ci.DateTimeFormat.Calendar))
                return;

            // Is the new calendar supported?
            if (Array.Exists(ci.OptionalCalendars, util.CalendarExists))
                ci.DateTimeFormat.Calendar = cal;
        }

        private CalendarUtilities(Calendar cal)
        {
            newCal = cal;

            // Is the new calendar a Gregorian calendar?
            isGregorian = cal.GetType().Name.Contains("Gregorian");
        }

        private bool CalendarExists(Calendar cal)
        {
            if (cal.ToString() == newCal.ToString())
            {
                if (isGregorian)
                {
                    if (((GregorianCalendar)cal).CalendarType ==
                        ((GregorianCalendar)newCal).CalendarType)
                        return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Posting code it not enough - you provide some explanation.

Answer (score 1):

i submitting this hope to save some one else time 
if you are using .net core and get this type of error 
Specified time is not supported in this calendar. It should be between ....
use some thing like this 
note you will get the error with some browser not all web browser will return this error
Firefox will never trigger this error almost chrome and IE and Edje will trigger this kind of errors

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult SetLanguage(string culture, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(culture))
        {
            return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
        }
        CultureInfo cInfo = new CultureInfo(culture);
        CultureInfo cInfoInvarian = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
        cInfoInvarian.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd-MM-yyyy";
        cInfoInvarian.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd-MM-yyyy";
        cInfoInvarian.DateTimeFormat.Calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        cInfo.DateTimeFormat.Calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        Response.Cookies.Append(
            CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
            CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(cInfoInvarian, cInfo)),
            new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(1) }
        );

        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

In windows go to change date and time setting > change calendar setting > change the calendar type to Gregorian.